# failed to retrieve message and resent chat in xabber-web

Tags: javascript, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe, mongoose-im

I've been using xabber-web for a month, and I am trying to connect it via bosh to mongoosim v.2.0, but it turns out failed to fetch the history chat (mam). 
The weird part is I can see the message stanza's in the debug and dev mode in browser.
In state of frustate and confused, I tried to connect it again to a different server, ejabberd, and it's completely success. The messages are retrieving, and there's a recent chat, and all sort of feature, but what I want is to connect to mongoose.
Is there any specific configuration in mongooseim for mod_mam, the xabber is support mam:1.

Maybe this will help, message stanza from different server:
**ejabberd result :**

```
<message to="admin3@localhost/xabber-web-9a95517d-d3cc-451e" from="admin3@localhost" xmlns="jabber:client">
   <result id="1508851147555271" queryid="3efd1fe7-e97f-4b92-b256-8d3e755eee28" xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:1">
      <forwarded xmlns="urn:xmpp:forward:0">
         <message id="2a66dda9-5440-490a-8f1e-7fb866a14082" xml:lang="en" to="admin10@localhost" from="admin3@localhost/64881300220952593792741" type="chat" xmlns="jabber:client">
            <archived id="1508851147555271" by="admin3@localhost" xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:tmp"></archived>
            <stanza-id id="1508851147555271" by="admin3@localhost" xmlns="urn:xmpp:sid:0"></stanza-id>
            <active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"></active>
            <body>asf</body>
         </message>
         <delay from="localhost" stamp="2017-10-24T13:19:07.555271Z" xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay"></delay>
      </forwarded>
   </result>
</message>
```

**mongooseim result**

```
<message id="e579cbc2-dd63-4bcc-8078-665e720bad6d" xmlns="jabber:client" from="admin3@localhost" to="admin3@localhost/xabber-web-17bcf9fc-8424-4688">
   <result id="ANFEVKG11B81" queryid="d2155cbe-1137-4532-bd64-2832ba97885d" xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:1">
      <forwarded xmlns="urn:xmpp:forward:0">
         <delay xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" from="admin3@localhost/xabber-web-eaa21c41-a11c-4399" stamp="2017-11-14T10:38:33Z"></delay>
         <message id="93470005-3c10-4eca-a4a8-9ed417d58969" from="admin3@localhost/xabber-web-eaa21c41-a11c-4399" xmlns="jabber:client" xml:lang="en" to="admin2@localhost" type="chat">
            <body>fsa</body>
         <markable xmlns="urn:xmpp:chat-markers:0"></markable>
         </message>
      </forwarded>
   </result>
</message>
```

Comment: anything in the browser (I assume there's a browser involved) developer tools console that may be of interest?

Comment: @JaromandaX no i think is not the browser problem,but i assume the problem is in the mod_mam,or rather in the server configuration,because there's no error in dev tools console (rather the error is in the strophe js log)